# mongo equivalent of sql query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i need to build a mongo query to get results from a collection which has the same structure as the following sql.

[click for picture of table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2BEz.png)

my sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    db.date,
    db.points,
    db.type,
    db.name,
    db.rank,
    YEARWEEK( db.date ) AS year_week
  FROM _MyDatabase db
  WHERE
    db.personId = 100 AND
    db.date BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2015-09-30'
  ORDER BY
    YEARWEEK( db.date ),
    db.type,
    db.points DESC
  ) x
GROUP BY
  x.year_week DESC,
  x.type;
```

the result looks like this

```
date          points  type name    rank year_week
-------------------------------------------------
23.10.2014    2000    1    Fish    2    201442
12.10.2014    2500    1    Fish    2    201441
16.10.2014    800     2    Fish    2    201441
```

i have tried different group / aggregate queries so far, but i couldn't get a similar result. hopefully one of you has more mongo experience than i and can give me a hint on how to solve this.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your schemas?

Comment: Please post the group/aggregate queries which got you closest to the result so we can help you to identify the mistake you made.

Comment: Your MySQL query is using a (mis)feature of the language that has columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  This is explicitly documented to return indeterminate values for those columns.

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this:

```
var start = new Date(2012, 9, 1),
    end = new Date(2015, 8, 30),
    pipeline = [
        {
            "$match": {
                "personId": 100,
                "date": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "date": 1, "points": 1, "type": 1, "name": 1, "rank": 1,
                "year_week": { "$week": "$date" }
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {
                "year_week": 1, 
                "type": 1,
                "points": -1
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "year_week": "$year_week", 
                    "type": "$type"
                }
            }
        }
    ];
db.getCollection("_MyDatabase").aggregate(pipeline);
```